# How to call a component function if a data changes in store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I want to trigger a method(serviceSelected) when state of a variable changes. I am trying to use computed but it is not working. My variable is in vuex store which is having a getter as getServiceSelected

```
computed: {
...mapGetters(["getServiceSelected"]),
serviceChanged() {

  this.serviceSelected(this.getServiceSelected);
  return this.getServiceSelected
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `watch`er instead

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getServiceSelected"])
},
watch: {
    getServiceSelected(newValue, oldValue) {
        // do something
        this.serviceSelected(newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: new value will be computed one, but what will be old value ?

Comment: Old value will be the value before the data changes, everytime `getServiceSelected` is changed, it will call `getServiceSelected` watcher, and you can use the `newValue` (what it's changed to) and `oldValue` (what it's changed from)

Comment: Ok, its working thankyou very much I was stuck since yesterday.